Why is there no way to get the cursor position in monaco-editor?
I read the API document
I want to get the cursor position (row, column), such as :

But seems there is no API for this function, is there any way to implement it?

the demo code here

before ask question I have searched this one QA:
Get absolute (index) position of cursor in Monaco Editor
but when I execute:
console.log(monacoRef.current.editor.getPosition())

I get the error:
Property 'getPosition' does not exist on type 'typeof editor'. ts(2339)


you can use onDidChangeCursorSelection event to get current carret position.
sample :
 editor.onDidChangeCursorSelection(e => {
            console.log(e)
  })

